# Using Sum function in R to set a variable from 3 different columns with specified amount

Tags: r

I am trying to create a character vector that stores the names of countries with 10 or more total medals in R. I am getting back an 'Error: attempt to apply non-function' when running the code.
Here is the code:
biggest_winners=olympic_df$name(sum(olympic_df$medals.gold & olympic_df$medals.silver & olympic_df$medals.bronze >=10))

here is a picture of the first 10 rows with column headers for reference:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new column with the sum by row by using `rowSums` and then filter for values superior to 10:

```r
olympic_df$Sum <- rowSums(olympic_df[,3:5])
olympic_df[olympic_df$Sum >= 10,]
```

Or in a single line:

```r
olympic_df[rowSums(olympic_df[3:5]) >= 10,]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
library("dplyr")

# Selects those 3 columns Gets the sum of three columns for each row
medal_count = olympic_df %>% select(medals.gold, medals.silver, medals.bronze) %>% rowSums()

# Filters the original dataset when sum of medals for a row > 10
olympic_df[medal_count>10,"name"] %>% unique # Returns distinct name
```